# MySQL Entity Injection

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, mysql.data

Does mysql.data.entity have built in protection against injection attacks. I feel like it should as it doesn't pass in literals, but rather objects so they should never touch SQL, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst one cant be certain without access to the MYSQL provider code, it is extremely unlikely there are issues with regard to injection.

The  [EF provider specification.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee828423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the 
[SQL generation based on trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee828422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) approach.
And the [sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider) would suggest it is not likely to be vulnerable.

Of course when one exposes direct SQL again eg via

> dbContext.Set.SqlQuery();   // or equivalent in < ef6 versions

then all bets are off.